# Duplex communication between two workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

How I can achiveve duplex communication between two workflows in WF 4.0. I know how to do that between a client and a workflow.

Comment: can anybody help on this plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a few blog posts about durable duplex communication [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/05/03/workflow-4-services-and-duplex-communications.aspx) and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/05/04/more-workflow-4-services-and-duplex-communications.aspx).

Comment: I already gone through your posts.. it's between a client and workflow.

Comment: That is in there, console app as the client and a workflow service as the workflow. With durable duplex the client always needs to be a complete WCF service because of the long running nature of workflows.

Comment: I used your second post passing the callback address and that worked. Thanks.